# Swift/iOS - Run code every 10 seconds in the background

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to run code every 10 seconds or so in the background? According to Apple's guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) my application does not fit any of their app types to keep the phone running for long periods of time in the background (ie. music player). I just want to make sure that there is no other way (in adherence with their guidelines) before giving up on my idea.